# How do I access a theme property in the Preferences in 2.93 with Python?

Tags: python, customization

I am trying to write a script to make the Dope Sheet bigger.

In *Preferences* it would be `ThemeDopeSheet.keyframe_scale_factor`

Have tried several ideas but nothing works.

Comment: Have I stumped The Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get preference in python by `bpy.context.preferences`

```py
import bpy

new_value = 2.0
bpy.context.preferences.themes[0].dopesheet_editor.keyframe_scale_factor = new_value
```

Comment: YES !!!
Exactly what I needed.
Thank Yo SO Much !!!

Comment: if this works for you consider to mark it as accepted answer ; )